# HTML momentarily pauses loading to process PHP, the result is ugly

Tags: php, html, performance, google-chrome, browser

Not sure if I really need my specific code for the example since this is a pretty simple scenario. I've got a php file:

```
<html>

    <?php

     *Some code hat pulls data from a database. This involves queries, for loops, etc.

    ?>

</html>
```

The problem only happens on Google Chrome: the page starts loading, processes the PHP and THEN gets to closing the  tag. This causes an ugly slide-down type effect where the next page looks like it's loading over the previous one.

[image]

That's how it looks for a moment in Chrome, and I know I'm doing something in a very unorthodox way. I really don't know the conventions of php yet, but I'm learning fast.

What should I be doing different? I prefer not to close the  tag before the php code, because then things will be out of place and everything after the php, of course, won't be contained in the html tag.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that it happens during the redirect after you log in!

EDIT:

```
   <?php 

    require 'autoload.php';



use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseRelation;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

session_start();
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

if ($currentUser) {

} else {

header("Location: http://rev-u.co/login");
exit();

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noticia+Text' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.2.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/responsive.css">


  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script src="/js/star-rating.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link href="/css/star-rating.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/centralpage.js">
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  </head>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1 class="brand">
        Rev-u
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="topbuttons">
      <form action="/logout.php">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="login">
          Logout
        </button>
      </form>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="profilebutton">
        My Profile
      </button>
      <a href="index">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary active" id="homebutton">
          Home
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="recentfeedcontainer">
      <h3>
        Recent Reviews:
      </h3>

      <div class="loadercontainer">
        <div id="circularG" class="recentloader">
          <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG">
          </div>
          <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG">
          </div>
          <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG">
          </div>
          <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG">
          </div>
          <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG">
          </div>
          <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG">
          </div>
          <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG">
          </div>
          <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

 <?php
$url;
$currentfriend;
$friendname;

// $currentUser

$relation = $currentUser->getRelation("FriendRelations");
$results = $relation->getQuery()->find();

if (count($results) != 0)
    {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)
        {
        $object = $results[$i];
        if ($results[$i]->get("profilePicture") != null)
            {
            $url = $results[$i]->get("profilePicture")->getUrl();
            }
          else
            {
            $url = "img/batmanfacebook.jpg";
            }

        $currentfriend = $results[$i]->get("username");
        if ($results[$i]->get("name") != null) $friendname = $results[$i]->get("name");
          else $friendname = $currentfriend;
        $query = new ParseQuery("Reviews");
        $query->equalTo("User", $currentfriend);
        $query->descending("createdAt");
        $result = $query->first();

        // $review = $result->

        get("text");

        // $rate = $result->

        get("Rating");
        if (count($result) > 0) echo '
<div id = "reviewitem" class=reviewitem_"' . $i . '">
<input id="input-id' . $i . '" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=1 data-size="xs" data-show-caption="false" data-show-clear="false" readonly="false">
<div id = "reviewimgcontainer" class="reviewimgcontainer_' . $i . '">
<img src="' . $url . '">
<h5>
<a href="/u/' . $currentfriend . '">
' . $friendname . '
</a>
</h5>
</div>
<p>
' . $result->get("text") . '
</p>
</div>
';
        }

?>
      <script type="text/javascript">


        $('.loadercontainer').addClass('hidden');


      </script>

      <?php
    }


?>


      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="friendscontainer">
    <h3>
      Following
    </h3>

    <ul>


    </ul>


    <div class="loadercontainer">
      <div id="circularG">
        <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG">
        </div>
        <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG">
        </div>
        <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG">
        </div>
        <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG">
        </div>
        <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG">
        </div>
        <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG">
        </div>
        <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG">
        </div>
        <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG">
        </div>
                  </div>
    </div>


</div>



<div class="friendstab">
<img style="border-radius:5px; box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 1.2px 0.5px;
margin-top:235px; width:40px; height:40px" src="img/friends.png">
</div>



</html>
```

Comment: Is it on a production box, can you provide a link to the site that is doing this? What version of Google Chrome are you using? Major Version numbers change every 6 weeks for Chrome, so what I might be using, you might not be using, and you should always check to see if you have the latest version of the client. Also if your doing web design, I highly recommend downloading the [Canary version of Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html?brand=KERZ#eula) as well.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out. And the site is rev-u.co. It is what I'm working on.

Comment: Uhhhhhhmmmmm you probably want to invalidate your keys now. Just sayin...

Comment: Yeah, wasn't thinking. Thanks for reminding me. At work.

Answer (score 1):

PHP gets executed on the server and then the result is sent to the browser. The browser never sees any PHP code. You must have done something different wrong. Maybe it's better to share your full code with us.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks for the help in understanding this beast. Added my code.

Comment: And I'd agree with you except the problem is resolved by moving the php code.

Comment: PHP may be set up to send only a part of content in time

Answer (score 1):

Always do Database Queries and intense loops *BEFORE* any output goes to the client. You're codes general structure should look like this ...

```
<?php
    // Some code hat pulls data from a database. This involves queries, for loops, etc.
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>blah</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>I'm the content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And then just echo the variables where they need to go?

Comment: Why? I can see a benefit in improving error handling but how does this improve performance?

Comment: On second thought, how can I get the data before the HTML and then insert the data into the middle of the HTML?

Comment: You may get data from DB, then just echo them later: `<?php /* fetch data*/ ?><html>(...) echo $result; (...)</html>`

Comment: Yes, it's what I ended up doing, but I wasn't sure if there was another way.  Sure, the user doesn't have to watch the page load and when it doesn, everything is already loaded, but the actual page takes a bit longer to appear since the output is waiting for PHP to finish at the top. Should I be worried about the extra second it takes for the user to actually see the page?

Comment: @RohitSharma, kinda but only if your selling something. [Amazon did a study that for every 100ms load increase they lost 1% of sales revenue](http://blog.gigaspaces.com/amazon-found-every-100ms-of-latency-cost-them-1-in-sales/). But if that's a problem for you, then throw hardware at it, after all [Hardware is Cheap, Programmers are Expensive](http://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/) can't afford the hardware, [Refactor the Low Hanging Fruit](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RefactorLowHangingFruit).

Answer (score 0):

Really should be voting to close this as too broad, but some hints might point you in the right direction...

Look at your network waterfall (developer tools). That will tell you if the delay really does occur in the HTML generation. It is rather unusual that you would get a chunked response unless you did an explicit flush (there are sometimes good reasons for doing this). It certainly has *nothing* to do with where you put your closing tags. If it is your PHP where the problem lies, use a profiler to isolate the problem.

Comment: Looking at http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dnzyPC/rev-u.co the RTT is rather high at 400ms but the problem seems to be the background image which is base encoded, way too high quality and loaded too late in the page generation cycle.

Comment: Oh, it's after you login and are redirected that it happens. I guess I haven't mentioned that...